# CSS hover on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html unordered menu list in the middle of my homepage. When clicking on one of the elements, i want it to move to the ultimate left and stay there.
However the code i have, makes the menu hover to the left on rollover (not click), and then the menu returns to the middle original location, and not stays in the left.
Any help?

```js
//jQuery
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.menu{

  width:150px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;   
  transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .8s, width.8s ease-out;
}

.menu:hover,
.permahover{
  opacity: 1;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <ul class="headlines">
    <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)">a</li>
    <li id="item2">s  </li>
    <li id="item3">d  </li>
    <li id="item4">d  </li>
    <li id="item5">F  </li>
    <li id="item6">Ta </li>
    <li id="item7">s  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So leave only `.permahover{` on `.menu:hover,.permahover{` line

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you want me to do,,, I'm new in javascript

Comment: Remove the `.menu:hover` from your CSS and leave it as just `.permahover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.menu:hover` from css to prevent it getting rollover on hover
Add jquery file,so that u can use jquery functions

```js
//jQuery
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.menu{
  width:150px;
 height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none; 
}
  .menu li{  
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
}
#item7{
  transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
}
#item6{
  transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
}
#item5{
  transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
}
#item4{
  transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
}
#item3{
  transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
}
#item2{
  transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
}
#item1{
  transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
}
.permahover li{
  opacity: 1;
  left: -135%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--HTML-->

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <ul class="headlines">
    <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)">a</li>
    <li id="item2">s  </li>
    <li id="item3">d  </li>
    <li id="item4">d  </li>
    <li id="item5">F  </li>
    <li id="item6">Ta </li>
    <li id="item7">s  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i removed the specified line in css. however it's not working.. Where do exactly i use the jquery source?

Comment: you used jquery for 'click' event...so you need to include jquery source in your html using  <script>  tag

Comment: dear it worked.. Thank you.
just one thing... Can i manipulate it in a way, that when i click on an element it'll move to the ultimate left in the form of a side of a triangle (/)
before taking the final form which is showed in the code u provided.

Comment: so you want that all items should move at different speed??

Comment: yes if that will make it move to the left in a form of a side of a triangle like this-->   /

Comment: Dear, you're great...That's exactly what i want.. but just one problem.. The menu is no longer positioned in the center of the website as before..i tried changing it but no success,, any ideas?

Comment: yeah forget to add that style...check again...could you please accept the answer so that it will help others also

Comment: I have another question posted, but no answer on it.. Just looking for code of an image slider.. If you can check it please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/qabf8ewa/1/

```
.menu:hover,
.permahover {
}
```

This selector was applying the class on hover and not just on click as you wanted

```
$("li").on("click", function () {
   $(this).parent("ul").addClass('permahover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vn3Lcoap/)

made some changes in the css code also

```
.menu{
  width:100%;  
  position: relative;
  border-style:none;   

}
.headlines{
   margin:0px auto;
}
.headlines li{
  width:150px;
  margin:0px auto;
  transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, width .8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .8s, width.8s ease-out;
   position:relative;
}

.permahover{
  opacity: 1;
  width:100% !important;


}
```